# Login Issue in Spring Application Deployed on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I deployed a Spring Application on Elastic Beanstalk for production. 
Application Components 
1. Spring 4 
2. Hibernate 
3. MySQL 
4. Apache Tomcat

Deployment Configuration 
  1. Initial JVM heap size :256m 
  2. Maximum JVM heap size :512m 
  3. Maximum JVM permanent generation size: 512m  
  4. AWS Server instance : m3.medium 
  5. RDS instance class : db.t1.micro  
  6. RDS storage : 5GB

Issue : No user able to Login after random interval of time for 5 minutes after that everything become normal.Random interval may be 12 Hrs,20 Hrs and more.

What actually happens : When user login after successful login user again come to login page.

Please help. 
1. Is issue related to spring security. 
2. Is something wrong with above configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your application.properties, or wherever Spring creates the connection pool for MySQL:

```
spring.datasource.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource.validation-query = SELECT 1
```

The issue seems to be that your application is losing connection with MySQL after certain time of inactivity.

Comment: One more point,user authenticated successfully then come back to login page.

Comment: that should be a separate question.

Comment: I mentioned this above What actually happens : When user login after successful login user again come to login page. Can you please help